# getting pcm audio for visualization via Spotify iOS SDK

Tags: ios, audio, spotify

We're currently looking at taking our music visualization software that's been around for many years to an iOS app that plays music via the new iOS Spotify SDK -- check out http://soundspectrum.com to see our visuals such as G-Force and Aeon.

Anyway, we have the demo projects in the Spotify iOS SDK all up and running and things look good, but the major step forward is to get access to the audio pcm so we can sent it into our visual engines, etc.

Could a Spotify dev or someone in the know kindly suggest what possibilities are available to get a hold of the pcm audio?  The audio pcm block can be as simple as a circular buffer of a few thousand of the latest samples (that we would use to FFT, etc).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your link doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: oops, fixed that typo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subclass `SPTCoreAudioController` and do one of two things:

1. Override `connectOutputBus:ofNode:toInputBus:ofNode:inGraph:error:` and use `AudioUnitAddRenderNotify()` to add a render callback to `destinationNode`'s audio unit. The callback will be called as the output node is rendered and will give you access to the audio as it's leaving for the speakers. Once you've done that, make sure you call `super`'s implementation for the Spotify iOS SDK's audio pipeline to work correctly.
2. Override `attemptToDeliverAudioFrames:ofCount:streamDescription:`. This gives you access to the PCM data as it's produced by the library. However, there's some buffering going on in the default pipeline so the data given in this callback might be up to half a second behind what's going out to the speakers, so I'd recommend using suggestion 1 over this. Call `super` here to continue with the default pipeline.

Once you have your custom audio controller, initialise an `SPTAudioStreamingController` with it and you should be good to go.

I actually used suggestion 1 to implement iTunes' visualiser API in my Mac OS X Spotify client that was built with CocoaLibSpotify. It's not working 100% smoothly (I think I'm doing something wrong with runloops and stuff), but it drives G-Force and Whitecap pretty well. You can find the project [here](https://github.com/iKenndac/Viva/), and the visualiser stuff is in [VivaCoreAudioController.m](https://github.com/iKenndac/Viva/blob/master/Viva/VivaCoreAudioController.m). The audio controller class in CocoaLibSpotify and that project is essentially the same as the one in the new iOS SDK.

Comment: Wondrful, iken, thanks!

We're excited to bring our stuff to iOS and have support for Spotify -- I now look forward to sharing our progress with you!   Please find me on skype as andyomeara to talk more.  :)

Comment: Daniel!  Work continues on our app and we're looking forward to getting it out for all to enjoy!  Kindly look at this if you get a second, thanks!!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853839/bootstrapping-under-spotify-ios-sdk-basic-questions

Comment: Hey yall!  Check out Tunr in the app store to see the Spotify iOS SDK working hard and beautifully!  

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tunr/id948831179?mt=8