# Bootstrapping under Spotify iOS SDK -- basic questions

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, uri, spotify

Firstly, nice job to the Spotify iOS SDK team -- it's come a long way and it's not easy to make an async world for the sync-minded masses!  :)

We have a basic query usage question that's probably answered elsewhere, but it'd be helpful to have a dev be clear on the issue (plus, there may be some new query paradigms in the new iOS SDK that could be used).  Basically, our app embeds the Spotify iOS SDK, offering the ability for the user to choose high-level audio sources: "Stations" and the entries under "Your Music" ("Playlists", "Songs", "Albums", and "Artists").

So, it'd be infinitely helpful if a dev could outline which queries would be made from the iOS SDK level (and which subsequent queries would be made for the items above).  If it turns out that doing initial/root-level queries is best done via the web API, could a dev please outline the official/approved method for forming a URL query?

Also, is there's a whitepaper or formal Spotify doc that formalizes Spotify URIs?

Thanks!
Drew
SoundSpectrum

Answer (score 1):

In the iOS SDK, everything you need is in the `SPTRequest` object.

- `playlistsForUserInSession:callback:` gives you playlists.
- `savedTracksForUserInSession:callback:` gives you the user's saved songs.

To get the user's "Albums" and "Artists" lists, you derive this yourself from the list of saved songs - there's no API to fetch them separately.

Radio stations aren't available in our SDKs.

Comment: Hi @iKenndac !  I've gone through both the web endpoint API, and there doesn't seem to be any way to get a user's followings -- not even the current user's followings.  Why is this?  Development of our app (Tunr) is coming along nicely and we're about a month from beta, but it's very limiting that we can't offer the logged on user to browse anything they're following!  Is there any workaround and why would Spotify omit this?  In contrast, SoundCloud's API allows a caller to get a list of a user's followings, allowing our app to hierarchally navigate users and their tracks, etc.