# Spotify iOS SDK - Getting streaming pcm data for UI/Audio visualization from destinationnode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-audio, spotify

Simliar to this stackoveflow post: [getting pcm audio for visualization via Spotify iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394769/getting-pcm-audio-for-visualization-via-spotify-ios-sdk)

I am looking to add an AudioUnit callback on the destination node as suggested by a Spotify developer in the post above.

However, I am unable to figure out how to get the AudioUnit from the destination node. I have been researching Core Audio and its documentation; however, it is not clear as to how to get a reference to the audio unit in an existing AUNode.

Any help would be appreciated!
My ultimate goal is to create a reactive type of UI based on the power level from the audio stream.